# How do I use command line to compile Libero SoC projects?

Tags: fpga, libero

I want to use a shell script to compile my Libero projects. How can this be achieved? If anyone has done it, please let me know. The documentation from Libero is not very helpful at all.

Comment: +1 for the bad documentation

Comment: Closest I've got was from the GUI there's a File/Run TCL script, or Project/Run TCL Script dialog which lets you select and run ... a TCL script. That can be cobbled together from the TCL commands embedded in console output and/or log files. Details swapped out of my memory and on another computer, sorry.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that tcl script which it generates, but how to run it from command line it is not clear.

Comment: The documentation and forums offer little help with this mess of Libero tools. I am surprised they are even in business for so long as they are.

Comment: Do you have a Tcl distribution installed? There's probably one with Libero or you can install something lice ActiveTcl. You can either run the tcl shell direct (by running tclsh) and use the "source" command or, if you installed ActiveTcl, from the command line type "tclsh <your_file_name>.tcl"

Comment: ok once I have tcl interpret up and running what comes next? when it comes to Quartus, we have separate executeables for synthesis, fitter and generating programming files and the actual programmer that can all be run from the command line.

Comment: I completely agree with everyone about. The tools and documentation of Libero are a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is a bit late but according to their [documentation](http://coredocs.s3.amazonaws.com/Libero/2021_1/Tool/pf_tcl_cmd_ref_ug.pdf) section 1.12, you run:

```
libero SCRIPT:myscript.tcl "SCRIPT_ARGS:one two three"
```

The SCRIPT and SCRIPT_ARGS are case insensitive.

Comment: How is this getting downvoted? This is the correct answer, section 1.12 is correct. There aren't options, although bizarre, this is the correct syntax.